# Not able to add into mysql database using Talend Job

Tags: mysql, talend, data-integration

**While adding data into mysql database using Job, I am getting following errors**

*Starting job fillraw at 16:34 10/03/2016.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3955
[statistics] connected

Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'Net_Value' at row 2

Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Material_Description' at row 9

...

Comment: Please trim your post to contain only the required information and a single instance of the error message

Answer (score 0):

I'm new, but with some similar error, I debugged it with examining schemes and syncing. I suggest you do the same:

- compare output scheme with DB scheme
- check types both in Talend and database (my case I think was Talend String mapped to DB VARCHAR, but I forgot to put the exact size for VARCHAR on DB side)
- check sizes and precisions of all types (expecially if you have double / float / decimal differences)